# Do not include the condition itself in regex

Tags: regex

Here's the regexp:

```
/\.([^\.]*)/g
```

But for string `name.ns1.ns2` it catches `.ns1` and .`ns2` values (which does make perfect sense). Is it possible only to get `ns1` and `ns2` results? Maybe using assertions, nuh?

Comment: For the sake of clarification, could you add a few example strings with their desired matches?

Comment: @Wiseguy it just needs to catch anything after dots: `something.catch.catch`

Comment: Oh, so the match is currently including the `.` but you want to exclude the `.`? That's what's in your subpattern.

Comment: @Wiseguy exactly. Yes, it's in my subpattern, because I am not sure how to get what I need to...

Comment: So you want the _entire_ expression to match just what is currently matched by your subpattern? Does your regex engine support [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the capturing group, use its value, however you do it in your language.

JavaScript example:

```
var list = "name.ns1.ns2".match(/\.([^.]+)/g);
// list now contains 'ns1' and 'ns2'
```

If you can use lookbehinds (most modern regex flavors, but not JS), you can use this expression:

```
(?<=\.)[^.]+
```

In Perl you can also use `\K` like so:

```
\.\K[^.]+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but let's go through some options.

Your regex: `/\.([^\.]*)/g`

(Minor note: you don't need the backslash in front of the `.` inside a character class  `[`..`]`, because a `.` loses its special meaning there already.)

First: matching against a regular expression is, in principle, a Boolean test: "does this string match this regex".  Any additional information you might be able to get about what part of the string matched what part of the regex, etc., is entirely dependent upon the particular implementation surrounding the regular expression in whatever environment you're using.  So, your question is inherently implementation-dependent.

However, in the most common case, a match attempt does provide additional data.  You almost always get the substring that matched the entire regular expression (in Perl 5, it shows up in the `$&` variable).  In Perl5-compatible regular expressions, f you surround part of the regular expression with unquoted parentheses, you will additiionally get the substrings that matched each set of those as well (in Perl 5, they are placed in `$1`, `$2`, etc.).

So, as written, your regular expression will usually make two separate results available to you: ".ns1", ".ns2", etc. for the entire match, and "ns1", "ns2", etc. for the subgroup match.  You shouldn't have to change the expression to get the latter values; just change how you access the results of the match.

However, if you want, and if your regular expression engine supports them, you can use certain features to make sure that the entire regular expression matches only the part you want.  One such mechanism is lookbehind.  A positive lookbehind will only match after something that matches the lookbehind expression:

```
/(?<\.)([^.]*)/
```

That will match any sequence of non-periods but only if they come after a period.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like string splitting, which allows you to break a string into pieces around a particular string (such as a period)?

It's not clear what language you're using, but nearly every modern language provides a way to split up a string.  e.g., this pseudo code:

```
string myString = "bill.the.pony";
string[] brokenString = myString.split(".");
```

Comment: I'm not facing a particular problem, I'm interested how to do it with regex.